# How to avoid "WARNING: replacing module" in Jupyter?

Tags: module, julia, ijulia-notebook

I want to write a module in the local directory, load it into Jupyter and test it.

I put the module into file `MyModule.jl`:

```
module MyModule

export my_function

my_function() = ()

end
```

Then I load it in JupyterLab:

```
include("MyModule.jl")
using .MyModule

my_function()
```

This works fine with a fresh Julia kernel, but if I execute the cell the second time, I will get two warnings:

```
WARNING: replacing module MyModule.
WARNING: using MyModule.my_function in module Main conflicts with an existing identifier.
```

In principle, I can get rid of the second warning by switching from `using` to `import`, so to write `MyModule.my_function()`, but the first warning is always there.

I have tried adding `using Revise`, but it does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I found how to do it with `Revise`, the key is to use `includet` instead of just `include`:

```
using Revise

includet("MyModule.jl")
using .MyModule

my_function()
```